# Установлено несколько Oracle Client. Узнать какой из них используется

Tags: база-данных, oracle

Установлено несколько оралке клиентов.

Есть программа на с++ которая общается через оракл клиент.
Как узнать какую я версию использую и какой путь?

Comment: Убрал,так яснее?)

Comment: Да, так яснее. Посмотрите переменные окружения:  `$ env|egrep "^(ORA|TNS|NLS|LD|PATH)"`. Только в том же окружении, где запускается программа.